# Magento2: Eav atrribute magento2 equivalent

Tags: magento2, eav, eav-attributes

What is the equivalent Magento 1 :

```
$tmp = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute();
```

in Magento 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute` this class is equivalent to `Magento2`

```
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute;

/**
 * @var attribute
 */
protected $attribute;


/**     
 * @param attribute $attribute     
 */
public function __construct(        
    Attribute $attribute,        
) {

    $this->$attribute = $attribute;

}
```

Now you can use this like,

`$this->$attribute->isAllowedForRuleCondition()` // it depends on your need which method you want use